# Sencha Touch , AddCls to a button not working

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, phonegap-build

I know most users have asked this, But i cant seem to get it right.
I have button that needs to change color on initialize() function. here is an example of one.

```
            {
               xtype:"button",
               id:"showme_BTN",
               baseCls:"home-round-btns",
               html:'<img src="resources/icons/show_me.svg">'           
            },
```

My initialize function(), this runs as soon as the app launches.

```
   listeners: {
        initialize: function(){  
           //console.log("initialize() works");
           Ext.getCmp('showme_BTN').removeCls('home-round-btns'); //remove old class
           Ext.getCmp('showme_BTN').addCls('home-round-btns-red'); // add new class
        }
    }
```

You may ask why i want to do this, I want load personalized colors on different users, Thank You

Comment: How is this related to *Phonegap Build*? Please add that information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

`addCls` function Adds a CSS class to the top level element representing this component. It will not add the class in `baseCls` it will add class in `cls`.

**EDIT**
Your button code should be:

```
{
               xtype:"button",
               id:"showme_BTN",
               cls:"home-round-btns",
              html:'<img src="resources/icons/show_me.svg">'           
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can i fix this. can you modify my code

Comment: this wont work in my case because cls doesn't override the button style, only baseCls does. I did a hack to have working the way i wanted, Thanks

Comment: It can override...using css.Could you share your css

Answer (score 0):

based on ankit chaudhary

I know what you mean,

- but you should remove the base button styling inside your cls
- do not use baseCls for this
- other than that you could just add an additional CSS using addCls, which overwrites the baseCls you set

If you really have to go that way you need to:

```
var btn = Ext.Viewport.down('#showme_BTN');
btn.element.dom.classList.remove('home-round-btns');
btn.element.dom.classList.add('home-round-btns-red');
```

Further improvements:

- do not use id, but itemId
- use down/up instead of getCmp
- limit the use of getCmp/down/up and use a variable instead